Based on RPDs, how to tell which orbital ($2s$ vs $2p$ or $4s$ vs $3d$) is more stable ? How reliable is the "less shielded" argument?
Professor (from MIT $5.111$ class) argues that $E_{2s} < E_{2p}$ by just saying that, due to the little bump of $2s$ (on the left of its RPD graph), $2s$ is less shielded and, hence, has lower energy.

However, I think the opposite argument could very well be argued: we could say "since the RPD of $2p$ is on the left of $2s$ (yes, we can say it as well), then $2p$ is less shielded (and hence more stable)".

I think the true reason of $E_{2s} < E_{2p}$ lies in a more quantitative argument (still based on the RPDs though).

I also think, that this quantitative argument is the reason why $E_{3d} < E_{4s}$ (here again, despite the fact that $4s$ has a little bump on the top left of its RPD).



Unfortunately I don't have access to a comparative of $4s$ and $3d$ RPDs, but could anyone confirm me if I'm right on the two bullets I made above ?

For H (or H-like) atoms, E(2s) = E(2p), in context of Schroedinger nonrelativistic wave equation. Applying relativistic Quantum Electrodynamics, there is very tiny difference. //For atoms with more than one electron, E(2p) > E(2s), due different shielding and e-repulsion geometry. Note the using radial probability comparison to determine orbital energy is very tricky.

Note that, since these plots are almost always referencing strictly hydrogenic orbitals, you can actually calculate and plot them yourself.
Here are a variety of plots that you can peruse through that I've generated. Again note that these are for orbitals of only the H atom. 
I am not entirely sure I understand your first bullet point, but I can address the second. The trouble with assessing 3d and 4s is that the while the 4s orbitals have non-zero density at the nucleus, because the 3d has no radial nodes it is much more sensitive to changes in effective nuclear charge because the average radial distance for the 3d orbitals is less than that of the 4s. This is why K and Ca are [Ar]$4s^{1}$ and [Ar]$4s^{2}$, respectively, but the transition metals fill the 3d shell first. That is, the effective nuclear charge for Y onward is such that the energy of the 3d orbitals falls off a metaphorical cliff while the 4s decrease in energy less rapidly.$^{1}$

J. Chem. Educ. 2010, 87, 4, 444–448


Thanks for this! What is "average radial distance" ? Is that the most probable radius ?

Yes, that is correct.

I don't quite get your argument "most probable radius is smaller for $3d$ than for $4s$". One could argue as well that most probable radius of $2p$ is less than most probable radius of $2s$. Yet, $2s$ is more stable than $2p$.

@legolizard No, average radial distance is not the most probable radius. Similarly as the most probable speed of an ideal gas molecule is neither linear nor quadratic mean speed. Average radial distance $d_\mathrm{avg}=\int_0^{\infty}{r  \cdot P(r)}\cdot \mathrm{d}r$
